# where he can overcome

Tags: clauses, subordinate-clauses

a. He is not a resourceful man, where he can overcome these obstacles.

b. He is not a resourceful man, such that he can overcome these obstacles.

c. He is not a resourceful man such that he can overcome these obstacles.

Are the above sentences grammatically correct?

I think (a) might work in speech, but I am not sure.

I think there's a small difference between (b) and (c). (b) is basically saying that he is not resourceful at all, while (c) is saying that he is not resourceful enough to overcome these obstacles. Is that correct?

Answer (score 3):

a) sounds very non-fluent to this US English speaker.

b) and c) mean basically the same thing, but neither sounds particularly fluent or natural.  b) in particular looks very odd because there is no reason to have a comma there.

*such that X* basically means "in a way that X", like

> The chess pieces were arranged such that White had no good moves

so you can see why it sounds strange to say "He is not a resourceful man *in a way* that he can overcome these obstacles."

A more natural way to say it would be

> He is not such a resourceful man that he can overcome these obstacles.

It is not *impossible* to phrase it the way you have done it, but it's less natural-sounding.